# The way to use OOP on a login procedure

Tags: php, oop

In the current login method:

```
 $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, username, active FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
        $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $sth->execute(array($username, $password));

        if (($obj = $sth->fetch()) !== FALSE)
            return $obj;
```

And on the login.php file.

```
$auth = new Auth($db);

$user = $auth->login('username', 'password');

if ($user) {
    if ($user->active == 0) { die('You must activate your account')}

    //If all is okay... Set the session variables...
}
```

But I was told that I rather would set the session variables in the login() method, but If I do so, how should I instead handle the checks like if the user is activated or not?

Comment: I do not see nothing wrong with Your approach. Why should You set the session within `login` function? Of course You can do that but then You will have to move the `active` check also into the `login` method.

Comment: It was a statement considering, code dependancy: This is a common mistake. Classes, generally, should not be dependent on any other file. No outside magical constants, variables, or classes should find their way into your models or controllers. Even if you aren't using an MVC pattern, it is good practice to make your classes completely self dependent, that way if something breaks you wont have to go hunting for it, it will all be self contained. So SITE_KEY and, in my opinion, those session variables should be defined inside this class.

Comment: And as it is also the approach of @nyson go accept his answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably create a structure like this:

```
class Auth {
  public function login($user, $pass);
  public function logout();
  public function loggedIn();

  private function getUserSession();
  private function updateUserSession();
  private function deleteUserSession();
}
```

login() checks against the database and on authentication success (if the user is active, user:password match and other tests) runs updateUserSession(). Ends by returning the result of $this->loggedIn().

logout() unsets the session with deleteUserSession().

loggedIn() checks against the session with getUserSession() and returns true or false if the user is logged in.

Comment: I guess that by `active` the OP thought of `the account being activated or not` and not about whether the user is active (logged in) or not...

Comment: I am interested about the logged_in part, could you improve it, examplify?

Comment: @John, `loggedIn()` will return true if the user is logged in or false otherwise... i think.

Comment: @nysson good approach, but "IsLoggedIn()" may be more comprehensible

Comment: @umlcat I think it's a matter of taste. I'll gladly pass up on the is if it's clear what the function does in an if-context. To me, `if($user->loggedIn())` is clear, even if I sound like a caveman saying it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in either procedure. The session vars are the same.

To check for an active user just add a " and userActive = 1" in your query. To deactivate a user just change this column to a 0 for that user.

Comment: I guess he want to load the existing user whether it is active or not and if the user is not active then let him know about the situation. If he'd select the user only if he is active he wouldn't know whether the user is just not active or he does not exist at all...

Comment: I see what you're saying. Its still something that's easy to query. He could even join to an 'activeuser' table and select the 'null' or 0 entry and use that to tell a user - 'you are active' or 'not'.